# How can I get single "a" to deslect in 2.8?

Tags: interface, shortcut

I'm using the 1-25-19 version of 2.8 beta. You have to double tap "a" every time you want to deselect something which is very annoying. Is there a way to make "a" work the old way where "a" selects all if nothing is selected and "a" deselects all if something is selected? ie. no double tap and no alt?

Answer (score 6):

Since Blender 2.8 is still beta, this option might still be moved around in the Options but right now it should be under "Menu - Edit - Preferences - Keymap" and there on the right side under "Preferences - Select All toggles".

[image: Select All toggles]