# How do you limit selection by the A hotkey to only the selected armature in pose mode?

Tags: shortcut, pose-mode, select

In the previous version, tapping <kbd>A</kbd> twice while in *Pose Mode* selected all visible bones of the currently selected armature. In the new version it selects all bones of all visible armatures instead. Is there a way to get the old behavior back?

Old behavior (preferred)
[image]

New behavior
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130641/how-can-i-get-single-a-to-deslect-in-2-8/130654#130654

Comment: @RonJensen Not the issue, I want it to only select the bones of the active armature, like in 2.79, but in 2.8 it selects all bones of all armatures of all layers.

Comment: It is because 2.7 doesn't allow pose mode of multiple armatures at the same time while 2.8+ does. If you don't want the bones of the other armature to be selected when you press A, you need to only select one armature berore entering pose mode.

Comment: What I mean is, in 2.7 when you have two or more armatures selected and you go to pose mode, only the active one goes in pose mode and the others stay in object mode, that's why you only select the bones of the active one when hiting A. Multiple object edits has only been introduced since 2.8+